# SpinLock scalability and limitations

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, throughput, spinlock

I have written a simple program to test the throughput of the CLH lock. 
I have the code just as described in "The art of multicore programming" book. Next I ran a counter on a changing number of threads for 10 seconds and defined counter/10.0 as the throughput.

My question is whether the results I've gotten are within logical range and what might be the reason they are the way they are. I ask because the dropoff in throughput for the CLH lock is extremely fast.
These are the results for the cLH lock, where the left specifies the thread count and the right is the throughput (size the counter got to with each thread incrementing it once in the critical section protected by the CLH lock, divided by 10).

`CLH
1   2.89563825E7
2   1.33501436E7
4   5675832.3
8   15868.9
16  11114.4
32  68.4`

As you see the dropoff is insane and makes me think that I may have messed something else up.

This is my code for the CLH lock (just as it is in the above mentioned book):

```
static class CLHLock implements Lock {
    AtomicReference<QNode> tail;
    ThreadLocal<QNode> myNode, myPred;

    public CLHLock() {
        tail = new AtomicReference<QNode>(new QNode());

        this.myNode = new ThreadLocal<QNode>() {
            protected QNode initialValue() {
                return new QNode();
            }
        };

        this.myPred = new ThreadLocal<QNode>() {
            protected QNode initialValue() {
                return null;
            }
        };
    }

    public void lock() {
        QNode qnode = this.myNode.get();
        qnode.locked.set(true);        

        QNode pred = this.tail.getAndSet(qnode);
        myPred.set(pred);           
        while (pred.locked.get()) {}      
    }

    public void unlock() {
        QNode qnode = this.myNode.get(); 
        qnode.locked.set(false);       
        this.myNode.set(this.myPred.get());   
    }

    static class QNode {  
        public AtomicBoolean locked = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    }
}
```

The run consists of the main thread waiting for 10 seconds while the others attempt to lock, increment, and then unlock until a volatile boolean tells them that time is up.

Comment: In my experience most degradation is caused by cpu hogging in the spin. `while (pred.locked.get()) {}` could probably be more sociable with `while (pred.locked.get()) {Thread.yield();}`. May make no difference so only commenting.

Answer (score 1):

**About your CLH lock implementation**

The implementation looks fairly standard, with the exception of the busy spin. You are probably better off yielding or parking (although that will require slightly more code).

**About your benchmarking results**

Judging about the correctness of some code from its performance tests is a task that requires at least as much knowledge as judging about the correctness of some code from its correctness tests.

You are probably observing a multitude of side effects not directly related to your code. In order to minimize these effects, use a benchmarking tool like JMH, otherwise you are measuring something that's not necessarily your code.

Here's a speculative explanation about your results, that may be incorrect, but is totally plausible:

- With 1 thread, your code executes extremely fast, because there's practically no contention on the lock and there's no cache thrashing. You probably benefit from successful branch prediction and from JIT kicking in early without later deoptimization.
- With 2 and 4 threads, you get some drop in throughput. It's not too bad because you still have hardware threads, but now you experience some cache thrashing (maybe even false sharing), some coherency traffic, and maybe some branch misprediction (due to the shared infrastructure of your benchmark). Although you don't get increase in throughput from parallel execution, you are still OK.
- With 8 and 16 threads, you are now over the limits of available hardware threads on your machine. You start experiencing OS scheduling effects, much more significant cache thrashing, as well as significant contention in your code.
- With 32 threads you go over the limit of some of the fast hardware caching mechanisms (L1 cache, TLB) and downgrade to the next fastest mechanism. It's not necessary to go over the cache size limit to experience this, you may also go over the associativity limit.